# Android - Problem with two activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I've got a problem with my project. I'm trying to communicate between two activities but the problem is at the intent of an activity. I have a search activity that has a ListView, when I click on an item of the ListView I'd like to see details about that item but it doesn't happen. Is there someone can help me? This is the link about my project. http://www.mediafire.com/?b4zcqtbeah8wlx9   Thank you very much.

Edit:

This is Details activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Details extends Activity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.last_layout);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasExtra("selectedChild"))
    {
        final Child selectedChild = (Child) intent.getSerializableExtra("selectedChild");
        if (selectedChild != null)
        {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Title)).setText(selectedChild.getName());
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(selectedChild.getImage(),
                    "drawable", "com.test.com"));
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is Search activity:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class Search extends Activity {


private ListView lv1;
private EditText ed;
private String lv_arr[] = {
        "America",
        "Busta",
        "Cactus",
        "Fire",
        "Garden",
        "Hollywood",
        "King",
        "Laboratorio",
        "Malta",
        "Nespola",
        "Pera",
        "Rosa",
        "Sapone",
        "Verano",
};


private ArrayList<String> arr_sort= new ArrayList<String>();
int textlength=0;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
    ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);

    lv1.setClickable(true);
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {  
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

            Intent intent = new Intent(Search.this, Details.class);

        startActivity(intent);

                }
         { 
         }});
```

Comment: u mean your onclick handler is not called? or Activity is not launched. Or you are not able to get the data out of the intent in next activity? Wheres the problem? Post only the code oncreate of next activity and onclick handler of search activity.

Comment: I can't post the code, I can't format it properly. Sorry.

Comment: You are not passing any data in the intent to details activity how will it show?

Comment: I have to put an intent.putExtra in Search activity but I don't know what I need to write in it, so I can pass data from details to the new layout clicking on an item of ListView.

Comment: That's not a good enough effort on your part. You should make it easy for us to understand your problem. And dat can happen only when we see some code. Edit ur post and add some code.

Comment: Finally I got it, I added some code.

Comment: Its the same code. you have not added anything to it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The problem is between this two activities. In Search activity I need to put `intent.putExtra()`, it will be like `Intent intent = new Intent(Search.this, Details.class); intent.putExtra(); startActivity(intent);` but I don't know how complete it, if I write `intent.putExtra("selectedChild", selectedChild);` it gives me an error at the second selectedChild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading through [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to figure out what `putExtra()` does.
I have no idea what `Child` is supposed to be, however there is no `putExtra(String name, Child child)` method, so you are using this method wrong.

As suggested you can use a database for your data.

**Other option:**

You appear to be pulling two Strings from your `Child` class, `selectedChild.getName()` and `selectedChild.getImage()`. Instead you can pass in two strings as extras and pull those out of the Intent in your Details activity:

Search Activity:

```
intent.putExtra("NAME", selectedChild.getName());
intent.putExtra("IMAGE", selectedChild.getImage());
startActivity(intent);
```

Details Activity:

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME");
String image  = getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGE");
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Title)).setText(name);
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(image,
                "drawable", "com.test.com"));
```

Comment: It gives me an error at the `selectedChild` in the Search activity, it has a red line. How fix that problem?

Comment: Perhaps read my answer carefully or better yet, post the error.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work for me, or better I can't work it. Have you tried your code with mine? Could you post the project that works? Thank you very much.

Comment: I've put `intent.putExtra("NAME", selectedChild.getName());
intent.putExtra("IMAGE", selectedChild.getImage());` in Search activity but `selectedChild` has a red line under its name. The problem is: "selectedChild cannot be resolved".

Answer (score 0):

I didn't take a look in your code, as you did not straightly point out where you think your problem is.

However, more generally in regard of passing/using same data in two activities:
I think it might be a wise idea to use a small database where you read and write your data.
Every Activity could use it and so always has access to all and the latest version.

If you want to use your approach, Intents can pass data when you start a Intent via `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that taking a look at the project the problem was visible. My problem is at the Search activity (press menu button) and when I click on an item of the ListView it gives a new layout without any information on that item. I have a Details activity and xml data file. I have to put an intent.putExtra in Search activity but I don't know what I need to write in it.